# Action bar compatibility

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget

I notice that on the android developer web page, there is [THIS](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) document which is titled "**Action bar compatibility**" .

Does it show the action bar implementation with **old** android API **less than** v11 or does it show how to implement action bar with API v11 and greater? I get confused by this page.

Answer (score 2):

> This sample shows how to use the ActionBar design pattern on pre-API 11 devices and the built-in ActionBar on devices supporting API 11 or greater.

It shows 2 things:

1. How to use an action bar without the actual ActionBar object on pre-API 11 devices. A ActionBar is simulated.
2. How to use the ActionBar in Android 11+

Comment: Do you mean this document has assumed I have some support package which contain the action bar api if I am on pre-API 11 device? I mean if I am on pre-API 11 which does not support action bar, how can I use? This document always assume I have some support package installed , so it just show how to implement action bar,am I right?

Comment: Not exactly. It shows how to use the `real` ActionBar as well as how to use the `compatibility layer ActionBar`. You can add the compatibility library to your project by right-click->Android->Add compatibility library.